# Count numbers in ArrayList which are within certain range

Tags: java, arrays, list, netbeans, count

I'm adding several numbers that were entered by a user and adding them to array list.

My code so far:

```
package project143;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * @author --
 */
public class Histogram {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Input for grades
        int mark = 0;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100) {
            System.out.println("Enter students mark:");
            mark = input.nextInt();

            if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100) {
                list.add(mark);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Now, I need to count how many numbers from the `list` are within following ranges (0-29 , 30-39 , 40-69 , 70-100)

Once I know how many numbers there are within each range, I need to display "*" next to each range, so for example there are 10 numbers within range of 0 - 29, therefore I need to display 10 stars (******).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you thought so far, on how to implement it?

Comment: I suggest first solving a small case using paper and pencil. Look at what you did, and think about the steps and data storage you used. Try to translate that into Java.

Comment: *How can I achieve this?* since you know the `Java` you can quickly achieve this by your logical skill. Try yourself.

Comment: @vels4j I know some basics, just started it. The issue is I don't know syntax, functions that can be required to achieve this, e.g how do I get number from array?

Comment: @vels4j I don't see any claim to prior knowledge of Java in the question, and the problem appears to be a very basic exercise in loops and conditional statements, so I think it is safe to assume that the OP does not yet know Java, but is trying to learn it.

Comment: @IlyaKnaup If you know the logic of what you need to do, but not the syntax, I suggest reading either a textbook or a tutorial.

Comment: @RohitJain at the moment, I'm trying to use if else statements, to count how many numbers there are in each range, I'd still like to figure out how to do it with lists, as it seems to be a much "cleaner" way

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I assumed by his question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way without a list by putting this code in the loop you get input from...

```
 if (mark <= 29) ++bombout;
 else if (mark <= 39) ++fail;
 else if (mark <= 69) ++pass;
 else ++excellent;
```

...or if you want to use a List, iterate over it and put the code above in the loop.

Answer (score 6):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) you can write the following code.  First we set up the ranges you specified:

```
private ImmutableList<Interval> ranges = Lists.immutable.with(
    Interval.fromTo(0, 29),
    Interval.fromTo(30, 39),
    Interval.fromTo(40, 69),
    Interval.fromTo(70, 100));
```

Then we can use these ranges in the examples, using anonymous inner classes.

```
final MutableBag<Interval> countByRange = Bags.mutable.empty();
Interval inputs = Interval.from(5).to(100).by(5);
inputs.forEach(new IntProcedure()
{
    public void value(final int grade)
    {
        countByRange.add(ranges.detect(new Predicate<Interval>()
        {
            public boolean accept(Interval range)
            {
                return range.contains(grade);
            }
        }));
    }
});
countByRange.forEachWithOccurrences(new ObjectIntProcedure<Interval>()
{
    public void value(Interval range, int occurrences)
    {
        System.out.println(range + " : " + StringIterate.repeat('*', occurrences));
    }
});
```

You will need to replace the Interval input with your actual input (Scanner in your example).  I just wanted a simple set of inputs to test with.

The output of the code is as follows:

```
Interval from: 70 to: 100 step: 1 size: 31 : *******
Interval from: 40 to: 69 step: 1 size: 30 : ******
Interval from: 30 to: 39 step: 1 size: 10 : **
Interval from: 0 to: 29 step: 1 size: 30 : *****
```

With Java 8 Lambda syntax you can write the following:

```
MutableBag<Interval> countByRange = Bags.mutable.empty();
Interval inputs = Interval.from(5).to(100).by(5);
inputs.forEach((int grade) -> {
    countByRange.add(ranges.detect(range -> range.contains(grade)));
});
countByRange.forEachWithOccurrences((range, occurrences) ->
    {System.out.println(range + " : " + StringIterate.repeat('*', occurrences));});
```

If you want to try using collect instead of adding to the bag using forEach, the following code produces the same result.

```
Interval.from(5).to(100).by(5)
    .collect(grade -> ranges.detect(range -> range.contains(grade)))
    .toBag()
    .forEachWithOccurrences((range, occurrences) ->
        {System.out.println(range + " : " + StringIterate.repeat('*', occurrences));});
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 1):

Use 3 variables to count.  while you are adding the mark to list increase the variables according to conditions. At last print the starts by using that count variables.

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use 4 `int` variables to store 4 **ranges**.

**Eg:**

```
int range29;
int range39;
int range69;
int range100;
```

**-** `Loop` through the `List` to **count the number of entries in different ranges.**

**Eg:**

```
for(int i : list){

    if ( i>=0 & i<=29){   // better use Non-short circuit AND

          ++range29;
    }

  else if ( i>=30 & i<=39){   // better use Non-short circuit AND

          ++range39;
    }

  else if ( i>=40 & i<=69){   // better use Non-short circuit AND

          ++range69;
    }

  else if ( i>=70 & i<=100){   // better use Non-short circuit AND

          ++range100;
    }


}
```

**-** Now simply use a `for-loop` to print the **Number of stars according to the range variables.**

Comment: Why not just check the range at the time of filling the list. And you don't need to check the lower bounds, just upper bound is enough.